# Yii2, настроить правильный url по правилу

Tags: yii2, url

Добрый день. Пробую настроить ЧПУ, вот код web.php:

```
        'urlManager' => [
        // Disable index.php
        'showScriptName' => false,
        // Disable r= routes
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<action:>' => 'site/<action>',
        ),
    ],
```

При таком виде добавляется приставка site, к примеру: http://mysite/site/category/1

Хочу избавиться от слова site, но не знаю как, очень жду помощи

Comment: То есть путь остается тот же, шаблон находится в папке site, но из URL нужно убрать это слово

Comment: Добрый день. Category в адресе это действие контроллера SiteController actionCategory()?

Comment: Да, контроллер SiteController actionCategory()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добрый день.
Попробуйте начать со следующих правил:

```
rules => [
  '' => 'site/index',
  'category/<id:\d+>' => 'site/category'
  '<_a:[\w\-]+>' => 'site/<_a>'
]
```

Соответственно надо настроить ссылки.

```
Html::a('Link name', ['category', 'id' => $id]);
```

Порядок следования правил тоже имеет значение.

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло. Добавил еще для постов: 'view/<id:\d+>' => 'site/view',

Все работает!

Comment: Можете дать ссылку, где подробно можно почитать на эту тему?

Comment: Пожалуйста. Ссылок для изучения yii2 много))) Официальная документация на русском https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/docs/guide-ru. Официальная документация на буржуйском http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/index.html. Отличный блог не только по yii2 http://www.elisdn.ru/ , смотрите статьи с тегом "yii2". По последней ссылке найдёте видео по urlManager()